# Why std::string reference cannot take char*?

Tags: c++, string, reference

I have simple code.

```
template<typename T>
class NamedObject{
public:

    NamedObject(std::string& name, const T& value):nameValue(name), objectValue(value)
    {

    }

private:
    std::string& nameValue;
    const T objectValue;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    NamedObject<int> no1("Smallest Prime Number",2);//error
    NamedObject<int> no2(std::string("Smalledst Prime Number"),2);//works

    return 0;
}
```

When I make first parameter as non refrence, both no1 and no2 object gets created. But when I keep reference Visual Studio compiler gives following error,

> Error 1   error C2664: 'NamedObject::NamedObject(std::string &,const
>   T &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [22]' to
>   'std::string &'   c:\users\pkothari\documents\visual studio
>   2008\projects\stackoflw\stackoflw\stackoflw.cpp   36

If char * can be casted to std::string, why not to std::string& ? Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Binding a reference ≠ Constructing an instance

Comment: Another thing to consider: That's not a `char *`.

Comment: @user4581301 `const char*`?

Comment: To fix this, your function should accept `std::string const& name`

Comment: @M.M Tried, din't work. `NamedObject( std::string const& name, const T& value)`. Getting same error.

Comment: @PranitKothari You should see after making that change that different error messages occur (that are not related to the function parameter passing). You also have to `#include <string>`,  and change the class member `std::string& nameValue;` to `std::string nameValue;`.  [Working example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uCiMGd35pZYSU1id)

Comment: @M.M Thanks, got your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> NamedObject<int> no2(std::string("Smalledst Prime Number"),2);//works
> ```

That should not work in a standard compliant compiler. It is supported in MS Visual Studio C++ even though it is not standard C++.

Neither of the following calls should work when the expected argument is `std::string&`.

```
NamedObject<int> no1("Smallest Prime Number",2);
NamedObject<int> no2(std::string("Smalledst Prime Number"),2);
```

Both of them should work when the argument type is `std::string` or `std::string const&`.

Comment: Din't compiler creates nameless object for `std::string("Smalledst Prime Number")`?

Comment: I love how msvc extensions are so misleading so often

Comment: @PranitKothari, that's precisely why it cannot be bound to a non-`const` reference.

Comment: Only changing the parameter type will lead to runtime UB, as the class will contain a dangling reference

Comment: @M.M: Actually, only changing the parameter type will lead to a compile-time error as you can't initialize a `std::string&` member with a `std::string const&` parameter. But the fundamental risk is indeed there: reference members can indeed easily lead to dangling references. This is especially the case when the reference member isn't obvious. (`std::pair<int&,int&>` has obvious reference members)